# Can I use an external MOSFET to dim this high-power LED driver?

Tags: mosfet, led, pwm, filter, led-driver

I want to use the [PAM2861](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM2861.pdf) LED driver.

It can handle my intended load (1 A and two LEDs around 3 V per channel) and I know this because someone with a similar project used it. It's also available at JLCPCB which means I can get it assembled for me and still save money (not to mention the equipment I'd need to buy for reflowing correctly).

Problem with it is that the PWM frequency and resolution are limited. I want a better resolution and a higher frequency, but I can't find anything else in their catalog that will do.

Why not just use an N-FET inserted after the LED string and drive that FET with low-passed PWM from my Arduino? The low-pass also eliminates the flicker that comes with PWM (this is annoying if I want to use a camera anywhere near the thing). Here is a schematic:

[image]

As far as I can tell, looking at the typical application example and the block diagram (when I say look, I am still a newbie), I can't see this being problematic, but maybe it is.

Am I right to think all this would do is add more resistance to the string as the PWM duty cycle is lowered? Does this interfere with accurate voltage regulation/constant current switching?

Comment: This IC operates at 100s of kilohertz, how is this a problem for a camera?

Comment: Your modification has so many issues that it isn't worth salvaging. MOSFETs are awesome devices but they aren't magical. It is the gate to source voltage that controls the switch.

Comment: If zero flicker is a requirement, and you don't care about power, ditch the LED driver and make a linear constant current circuit.

Comment: I might be tempted to use a PFET or PNP - maybe even a JFET as a voltage-controlled resistor - to modify R1.  Keep everything else per the PAM's datasheet.

Comment: Or...having looked at the datasheet now, there's a handy little pin that you've left disconnected (which is a valid use for that one - it isn't always in general), that does exactly what you want.  See the Pin Descriptions on page 2.

Comment: Problem with that pin as described is that the resolution is limited. In voltage control mode it goes only down to 10% and in PWM mode the max frequency is low enough to cause cameras issues. 

However the idea to use a transistor of some kind to replace the resistor... Why didn't I think of that? It's brilliant actually. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Read the datasheet:

[image: Datasheet showing dimming using VSET pin]

If you must, drive that with a low-pass signal from your Arduino.